# Cleaning People/Group Data Exported from SharePoint 2010 Lists

Tags: sharepoint, excel, sharepoint-2010

If you have a list with a People/Group data type that allows multiple selections, the data you get in an Excel export is a bit dodgy.

Example:

Instructors:
Berry, Patrick;#10;Smith, John;#136

Is this just something I need to deal with in Excel, because it makes reporting based on people filtering somewhat challenging.

Comment: See this post which implies this is by design: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointgeneral/thread/00cc338d-8201-4b8d-b2ea-5979ee58a464

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel would be the best place to deal with it. The formatting is a part of how SharePoint store the data in the underlying field. 
The field is formatted #[list item id]; [list item name]; where the id comes from the Site collections list of users.

The issue with reporting is that you would probably want a separate line for each user in order to use any of the pivot functions in excel. This would be an exercise in VBA manipulations of the data.

Excel does allow the referencing the Microsoft VBScrip Regular Expressions 5.5 and a the regular expression `#\d+;?` should find the different values.